# Is it possible to have securely encrypt chat on server you don't trust?

Tags: encryption

Let's say I have app that just runs some encrypted chat on server I don't own. Is it possible to have the chat securely encrypted without the owner of the server having access to the encryption keys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the untrusted server is both hosting the software/web pages used for encryption and is relaying the encrypted messages then you cannot trust the encryption to keep your secrets because the software doing the encryption comes from an untrusted source.

If instead the software used for encryption comes from a trusted source and the untrusted sever is only relaying the encrypting messages then the server has no way to read or modify the messages, provided that the encryption was done properly. The server might at most try to disrupt communication by not forwarding some messages, duplicating messages or changing the message order. But properly done encryption should at least detect such manipulations.